# Maven add my own information during build to MANIFEST.MF file

Tags: maven, manifest, pom.xml

I need your help. I have to write a script adding versions of sub-projects to `MANIFEST.MF` file during build application by Maven.

I write some Mojo class that gets information I need (I named it `GenerateVersionPropertyFile.class`). Now I need know how to put this information to manifest file.

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                <generateClient>true</generateClient>
                <archive>
                    <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    <!--
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                    -->
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Built-By />
                    </manifestEntries>
                    <manifestSections>
                        <manifestSection>
                            <Name>appName</Name>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Implementation-Title>${project.name}</Implementation-Title>
                                <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                                <Implementation-Vendor-Id>${project.groupId}</Implementation-Vendor-Id>
                                <Implementation-Vendor>${project.organization.name}</Implementation-Vendor>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </manifestSection>
                        <manifestSection>
                            <Name>exampleApp</Name>
                            <manifestEntries>
                                <Implementation-Title>exampleEntry</Implementation-Title>
                                <Implementation-Version>dupa2</Implementation-Version>
                                <Implementation-Vendor-Id>${project.groupId}</Implementation-Vendor-Id>
                                <Implementation-Vendor>${project.organization.name}</Implementation-Vendor>
                            </manifestEntries>
                        </manifestSection>
                    </manifestSections>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      <plugin>  
           <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>  
           <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
           <version>1.1.1</version>  
           <executions>  
            <execution>  
             <phase>test</phase>  
             <goals>  
              <goal>java</goal>  
             </goals>  
             <configuration>  
              <mainClass>maven.GenerateVersionPropertyFile</mainClass>  
              <arguments>  
               <argument>${project.basedir}\src</argument>  
               <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument> 
              </arguments>  
             </configuration>  
            </execution>  
           </executions>  
          </plugin> 
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>server-ejb-build-devel</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>build-devel</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifestSections>
                                <manifestSection>
                                    <Name>app1</Name>
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
                                        <Implementation-Timestamp>${timestamp}</Implementation-Timestamp>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </manifestSection>
                            </manifestSections>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: why do you use a java class and not get it directly from the sub-module pom version tags?

Comment: Sorry mayby I described it wrong. When I said subprojects , I think about json schemas from project. I need to parse this files and get information from them so I used Java class to this.

Comment: hmm any chance of moving to gradle? it is very powerful for such things. just a thought

Comment: No way, it's not my project I have to do this in Maven.

Comment: try the exec plugin then. http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/

Comment: if this works for you, please let me post it as an answer so as to accept it. thank you

Comment: I don't know yet. I don't know how excec plugin works and how to use it in my case.
If you can say something more how to use it I will be grateful

Comment: havent actually used it but i know that if you want to execute an external java program, you can use this plugin. read also about toolchains.

Comment: First what does you class generate of information which should be put into MANIFEST.MF ?

Comment: First bind the exec-maven-plugin to `prepare-package` phase instead of `test` and let the class generate into `target/` folder instead of the `src`folder cause `src` is under version control never change the src folder. Only use `${project.build.directory}` instead. Second use `<manifestFile>${project.build.directory}/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>` to pick up the generated file...

Answer (score 0):

Have to use the `maven-jar-plugin` on your *pom*.

Example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <key>value</key>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-ejb-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, if you are adding custom properties in MANIFAST.MF file which build package is JAR/WAR.

if packaging JAR in your pom.xml file then use

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
                <mode>development</mode>
                <url>http://testing/</url>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**OR** if packaging WAR in your pom.xml file then use

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
                <mode>development</mode>
                <url>http://testing/</url>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```